# linking to files with angularjs to display as a fully qualified url

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering how I can hyperlink a file where the file info comes over on to the view in jason data as \DCV1\Sharedfolders\Ac...9454_INV_1312160600.pdf

how do I link this so it will open in the browser as a fully qualified url??

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if the json object contain

```
'url': 'some/url/tothe/file.pdf',
'name': 'file-name.pdf'
```

the template can link the file like this

```
<a ng-href="{{elm.url}}">{{elm.name}}</a>
```

Comment: the jason data comes as a string and references the location of the file. pdfUrl
 "\\DCV1\Sharedfolders\Accounting\Livingston\PDF\10827641612349_310_384153_INV_1312160600.pdf" I have it wrapped like this in the view... It converts it to a correctly formatted link but still does not open.  <a ng-href="file:///{{row.pdfUrl}}"><span class="icon-file"></span></a>

Comment: a href="file:///{{row.pdfUrl}}" target="_newtab".... so here is what worked in the end. Since we only use IE for our corporate portal, this solution is fine. If you are trying to use that in Firefox you won't be successful.